# alternative way of blades @extends via controllers?

Tags: laravel-4

Every view that I create I have to use @extends('my.layout.path'). Is there a way I can just tell the controller what layout the following views in the controller will be using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing on the [Templates docs page](http://laravel.com/docs/templates):

> One method of using templates in Laravel is via controller layouts. By specifying the layout property on the controller, the view specified will be created for you and will be the assumed response that should be returned from actions.

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    /**
     * The layout that should be used for responses.
     */
    protected $layout = 'layouts.master';

    /**
     * Show the user profile.
     */
    public function showProfile()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('user.profile');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

nm, i figured it out for anyone else this is what i did:

```
class MyController extends basecontroller
{
    protected $layout = 'layouts.admin';
}

class DashboardController extends AdminBaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->layout->content = View::make('admin.dash');
    }
}
```

then in the view i just have

```
@section('content')
... some html
@stop
```